# Don't use React for routing requests

Tags: ruby-on-rails, reactjs

I have a single page that is `React` and the rest of the website is (currently) `Rails`.

The `React` page has a single route and doesn't require any further routing.

I would like to send route requests back to the `Rails` server rather than have them picked up by `React`.  Currently you can use the `Rails` pages as expected until you enter the `React` page, at which point you cannot exit the `React` page regardless of URL.

When the `React` page is built, the build is moved to the public folder in the `Rails` application.  I use a controller action to call the `React` page by rendering the index page from the public folder.

```
Controller
  def react_index_html
    render file: 'public/index.html'
  end

Route
  get '/trade', to: "react#react_index_html", constraints: ->(request) do
    !request.xhr? && request.format.html?
  end
```

Let me know if I need to provide any more information to help.  I searched extensively on the net for an answer but my search combinations return info about `react-router` and routing inside the `React` page but couldn't find anything related to what I want to do.

*** Clarification:  The react page is hosted at /trade, basically any pathname that doesn't contain /trade should be routed by rails, not react.

Comment: Can you post your React page code?

Comment: It is a full React project, is there anything in particular you would like to take a look at?

Comment: The component that contains the route you're having trouble with.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It turns out that the mistake I made was that I hosted the page in the public folder and not the public/trade folder, with the homepage variable set in the package.json file with

```
"homepage": "www.publicurl.com/trade"
```

In my package.json file at the root of the rails project I had:

```
"build": "cd react-client && npm install && npm run build && cd ..",
"deploy": "cp -a react-client/build/. public/",
"postinstall": "npm run build && npm run deploy && echo 'Client built!'"
```

I changed this to:

```
"build": "cd react-client && npm install && npm run build && cd ..",
"deploy": "mkdir public/trade && cp -a react-client/build/. public/trade/",
"postinstall": "npm run build && npm run deploy && echo 'Client built!'"
```

Which did the trick, now any url's that aren't "/trade" get routed via the rails router.